# CKDatabaseSubscription not pushing notifications

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I'm trying to receive changes with `CKDatabaseSubscription` but I'm stuck that I don't receive any push notifications from that subscription.

I'm subscribing to changes in private record zone via such method:

```
let container = CKContainer.default()

func subscribeChanges() {
    let subscription = CKDatabaseSubscription(subscriptionID: "test")

    let notificationInfo = CKNotificationInfo()
    notificationInfo.shouldSendContentAvailable = true
    subscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo

    let operation = CKModifySubscriptionsOperation(subscriptionsToSave: [subscription], subscriptionIDsToDelete: [])
    operation.modifySubscriptionsCompletionBlock = { savedSubscriptions, deletedSubscriptionIDs, operationError in
        if operationError != nil {
            print(operationError)
            return
        } else {
            print("Subscribed")
        }
    }

    container.privateCloudDatabase.add(operation)
}
```

Subscribe is successful. But I don't receive any notifications on device, I've checked with such method:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {   
    NSLog("Notification received")

}
```

I'm testing on real device connected to XCode, tried to push changes via simulator and Apple's dashboard.

#### Update

As I've found `CKDatabaseSubscription` only works for shared record zones. For public & private zone I can use something like that and it works:

```
CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "TestRecordType", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE"), options: CKQuerySubscriptionOptions.firesOnRecordCreation)
```

Comment: Just struggling with that kind of problem and when I read your answers I am still confused. My question is: Does the CKDatabaseSubscription work with customZones in private database scope or do I have to use the CKQuerySubscription? Here you write, that the CKDatabaseSubscription only works on SHARED zones, but in the accepted answer (below) you write that it could work on PRIVATE custom zones as well. Apples documentation did not really help in that question. Pleas help.

Comment: @LukeSideWalker, `CKDatabaseSubscription` will fire notifications only for private and shared zones. So yes, it does.

Comment: Another confused person here. You wrote in your Update: "As I've found CKDatabaseSubscription only works for shared record zones.". This contradicts your most recent comment: "CKDatabaseSubscription will fire notifications only for private and shared zones"?!?

Comment: Are you able to use any of these techniques or any other way to cause CloudKit to notify the app or app extension that made the change to the CloudKit container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for know `CKDatabaseSubscription` will fire notifications only for record zones with `CKRecordZoneCapabilityFetchChanges`, all private custom zones have that capability (shared I think also), default zones not.

So only way now is to create new custom zone.